# High Score board

Tags: javascript

So I have this game where the score keeps increasing but theres no losing. When the player exit the game I want to save and store the game high score and show it in another page. How can I do that?

```
    checkColorMatch = function() {
        if (curColor == nextMatchColor) {
            ++streak;
            dur -= 10;
            if (dur < minDur) {
                dur = minDur;

            }
            streakCounter.innerHTML = streak;
        } else {
            streak = 0;
            dur = 2000;
            streakCounter.innerHTML = "";
        }


        prevMatchColor = nextMatchColor;
        nextMatchColor = chooseColor();

        boxes[0].className = "box " + colors[prevMatchColor];
        boxes[1].className = "box " + colors[nextMatchColor];

        rerun();
        setTimeout(checkColorMatch,dur);
    };

main.classList.add("run");
jello.classList.add(colors[curColor]);
boxes[0].classList.add(colors[prevMatchColor]);
boxes[1].classList.add(colors[nextMatchColor]);

for (b in boxes) {
    if (b < boxes.length) {
        boxes[b].classList.add(colors[chooseColor()]);
    }   
}

setTimeout(checkColorMatch,dur);

document.querySelector(".click-area").addEventListener("click",cycleColor);
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        cycleColor();
    }
});
```

Comment: you should add your html to question

Answer (score 0):

There is [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API to access Storage object of the Document's origin, which can be used to store your data, which persists after closing a page.

Comment: where can I add that?

Comment: @eme Anywhere where it is executed, `localStorage.setItem('player1', '78');` before the page the page is closed.